# Using formula to increase certain value in a cell

Tags: excel, string, text, excel-formula, substring

Consider I type in 001/SCIENCE/A.01/NATURAL in cell C4.
Is it possible to use a formula in order to get 001/SCIENCE/A.02/NATURAL in cell D4? or to get 002/SCIENCE/A.01/NATURAL in cell C5?
I've tried TEXT, STRING, SUBSTRING FUNCTION and other function, but none of them work.
Any ideas is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: in D4 `="001/SCIENCE/A."&TEXT(COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$4)+1,"00")&"/NATURAL"` .. and copy right  .. in C5 `=TEXT(ROW()-ROW($C$4)+1,"000")&"/SCIENCE/A.01/NATURAL"` .. and copy down

Comment: @NareshBhople it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **D4** enter:

```
=LEFT(C4,14) & TEXT(--MID(C4,15,2)+1,"00") & RIGHT(C4,8)
```

[image]